# Why worker thread transitions from CANCELLED to SCHEDULED skipping READY? (JavaFX2)

Tags: multithreading, javafx-2

**Update: I am finding the problem with other threads too; they enter Scheduled state but never transition to Running. why?**

My program has a Service that uses a Task to connect to a device through the serial port.
In other words,

```
public class ConnectService extends Service<String> {
   protected Task createTask() {
        return new ConnectTask();
    }

    class ConnectTask extends Task<ObservableList<String>> {
        @Override
        protected ObservableList<String> call() throws Exception {
            ...
            connect();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If a previous call to connect to the device got hung, then I want to cancel the task/thread and start over afresh in this attempt. 
In order to do this,

```
    if (connectService.getState() != Worker.State.READY) {
        connectService.cancel();
    }
    connectService.restart();
```

However in the debugger I am finding that if the state is SCHEDULED, then the above code sends it to CANCELLED. But restart() will not send it to READY - instead it goes back to SCHEDULED - and **call() does not get executed!**

This seems to contradict the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.State.html)

> A reusable Worker will transition from CANCELLED, SUCCEEDED or FAILED
>   back to READY.

I tried

```
   if (connectService.getState() != Worker.State.READY) {
        connectService.cancel();
        connectService.reset();
    }
    connectService.start();
```

Now state goes back to READY, but call() is never executed!

Comment: Have you tried adding `Worker.State.SCHEDULED` to the states excluded from your `if` condition?

Comment: @jball Do you mean `if (connectService.getState() != Worker.State.READY && connectService.getState() != Worker.State.SCHEDULED)` Will that help?

Comment: That's what I'd try. I don't have an environment to test it in so I'm reticent to post it as an answer, but it seems like your current code will catch the service in the `SCHEDULED` state and cancel it.

Comment: @jball But that is exactly what the present condition will catch - anything that is not in the READY state.

Comment: I think that's the problem, the `Worker` is guaranteed to enter the `SCHEDULED` state before the `RUNNING` state, so if it's stuck not being able to transition to `RUNNING`, a `cancel` and `reset` won't help. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Worker.State.SCHEDULED` to the states excluded from your `if` condition, i.e.

```
if (connectService.getState() != Worker.State.READY && 
    connectService.getState() != Worker.State.SCHEDULED) {

    connectService.cancel();
}
connectService.restart();
```

This is because the `Worker` will **always** transition from `READY` to `SCHEDULED` before it enters the `RUNNING` state. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.State.html)

> However even in cases where the `Worker` is executed immediately, the
>   `Worker` will temporarily enter the `SCHEDULED` state before entering the
>   `RUNNING` state. That is, the transition is always from `READY` to
>   `SCHEDULED` to `RUNNING` (unless of course the Worker in cancelled).

If for some reason your working is stuck in the `SCHEDULED` state, it's likely that the `cancel` and `restart` just returns it to the same stuck state.

Also, (not seeing the rest of your code, so this is just extrapolation) the idea of interrupting it when you catch it running on the assumption that it is hung seems shaky, since it could be working well but taking longer than expected, or it could be hanging every time you call it. If there's no test you can run within `connectService` to determine whether it's hung or not, then I guess you're stuck with something like this, but it feels problematic.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in trying your approach - I shall do so soon.

Comment: I fixed some thread contention issues and now I do not see the problem happen again - so I was unable to try and test the fix. However, I have accepted your answer as it seems logical.